# issue with the external dependency adding in liferay 7.4 module

Tags: liferay, ehcache, terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory

whan i want to add some external dependency in the build.gredle, module is Sanitized with
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.terracotta.entity.ehcache_ [Sanitized]
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: net.sf.ehcache; version="2.10.0"_ [Sanitized]

I want use the module for add cache data into bigmemory with the help of ehcache

Answer (score 0):

According to Liferay's versions.html (that you'll find in your download), ehcache is included in a version that my current installation lists as 2.10.6.LIFERAY-PATCHED-2 - That jar lists the exported package as version 2.10.6.

In case your terracotta version, or your custom code, explicitly demands 2.10.0, the dependency will not be met. It should request 2.10.x or 2.10.6

As you don't state how you build your custom module, this is as far as the answer can go: You'll need to adjust your build process to either demand the currently deployed version, or to losen the requested version to just the first two digits of the semver version.